# .htaccess and mod_rewrite as a replacement for httpd.conf

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, replace, httpd.conf

I need http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-token/#Apache_Configuration installed and configured.
Howether my hosting (VPS) doesnt give access to httpd.conf. I was advised to use mod_rewrite and .htaccess instead. I need to set up this data :

```
<Location /downloads/>
      AuthTokenSecret       "secret string"
      AuthTokenPrefix       /downloads/
      AuthTokenTimeout      60
      AuthTokenLimitByIp    off
</Location>
```

Question is - how is the proper way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot.

[**`Location Directive`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location) is only allowed in Apache config and not allowed in `.htaccess`

Comment: I see - just to be sure - there is absolutly no way to configure http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-token/ without access to httpd.conf ?